# Excel VBA Improve code performance with Log Function

Tags: performance, excel, vba

Any idea on how to improve the performance of the code below?

I'm your average engineer (i.e., not a savvy programmer) and was fiddling with a VBA project to get it to run faster. It was taking days, now I got it to run in a couple of hours, but I know that it can be even faster, and the most time consuming part is this one.

I feed the code below with thousands of vectors with Acoustic/Vibration spectra information. For each spectra the code takes about 30 secs to run.

```
    Sub time_test()

        '################################################################################################
        'This is just to simulate the vector of input data which in reality would be an acoustic spectrum
        Dim yval(8000000, 1) As Double
        Dim val(8000000, 1) As Double
        For i = 0 To 8000000
            yval(i, 0) = 100 * Rnd
        Next i
        Length = 8000001
        '################################################################################################


        '@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
        'From here on is where I must improve the performance of the code
        Timing = Timer

        For Index = 1 To Length
            val(Index - 1, 1) = 20 * Log10(yval(Index - 1, 0), "Pre")
        Next Index

        Debug.Print Round(Timer - Timing, 2)
        '@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

    End Sub

    Public Function Log10(Valeur As Double, sType As String) As Double

        Select Case sType
            Case "Vib"
                If Valeur <> 0 Then
                    Log10 = Log(Valeur) / Log(10#)
                End If
            Case "Pre"
                If Valeur <> 0 Then
                    Log10 = Log(Valeur / (2 * (10 ^ -5))) / Log(10#)
                End If
        End Select

    End Function
```

Comment: To improve performance remove the `Valeur <> 0 ` testing.  Also replace the re-calculated constants.............get rid of `Log(10#)`, etc.

Comment: Make separate functions for `Vib` and `Pre` to remove excessive `Select Case`.

Comment: To amplify the comment from @Gary'sStudent, for case "Vib": `Log10 = 0.434294481903252*Log(Valeur)` and for case "Pre":  `Log10 = 0.434294481903252*(Log(Valeur) + 10.8197782844103)`